# Change UILabel in Collection View Cell on Motion Event (Shake)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, shake

Trying to change a UILabel in a UICollectionViewCell using the shake motion event. With my limited knowledge, it appears you cannot detect a motion event within a cell; only the View Controller.

Here's what I have in my ViewController so far, which is the delegate for many CollectionView cells:

```
override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {

    // Get the indexPath by visible card
    var visibleCurrentCellIndexPath: IndexPath? {
        for cell in self.collectionView.visibleCells {
            let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
            return indexPath
        }

        return nil
    }

    print("shake & bake on card #\(String(describing: visibleCurrentCellIndexPath))")
}
```

I can get the indexPath of the visible cell, but I don't know what to do from here to change the UILabel of the cell at the indexPath (visible cell)
 [image: Image Example].

Answer (score -1):

```
override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let mObs = MotionObservable()
        mObs.addGyroObserver(observer: {(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double) -> Void in

            //let summary = Int(abs(x) + abs(y) + abs(z))
            //print("Shake Value : \(summary)")
            //mObs.clearObservers()

            //Do you thing

        })
        //self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

import Foundation
import CoreMotion

let Fps60 = 0.016

class MotionObservable {

    let motionManager: CMMotionManager
    let updateInterval: Double = Fps60

    var gyroObservers = [(Double, Double, Double) -> Void]()
    var accelerometerObservers = [(Double, Double, Double) -> Void]()

    // MARK: Public interface

    init() {
        motionManager = CMMotionManager()
        initMotionEvents()
    }

    func addGyroObserver(observer: @escaping (Double, Double, Double) -> Void) {
        gyroObservers.append(observer)
    }

    func addAccelerometerObserver(observer: @escaping (Double, Double, Double) -> Void) {
        accelerometerObservers.append(observer)
    }

    func clearObservers() {
        gyroObservers.removeAll()
        accelerometerObservers.removeAll()
    }

    // MARK: Internal methods

    private func notifyGyroObservers(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double) {
        for observer in gyroObservers {
            observer(x, y, z)
        }
    }

    private func notifyAccelerometerObservers(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double) {
        for observer in accelerometerObservers {
            observer(x, y, z)
        }
    }

    private func roundDouble(value: Double) -> Double {
        return round(1000 * value)/100
    }

    private func initMotionEvents() {
        if motionManager.isGyroAvailable || motionManager.isAccelerometerAvailable {
            motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = updateInterval;
            motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()
        }


        // Gyro
        if motionManager.isGyroAvailable {
            motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = updateInterval
            motionManager.startGyroUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!, withHandler: { (gyroData: CMGyroData?, NSError) -> Void in
                let rotation = gyroData!.rotationRate
                let x = self.roundDouble(value: rotation.x)
                let y = self.roundDouble(value: rotation.y)
                let z = self.roundDouble(value: rotation.z)
                self.notifyGyroObservers(x: x, y: y, z: z)

                if (NSError != nil){
                    print("\(String(describing: NSError))")
                }
            })
        } else {
            print("No Gyro Available")
        }

        // Accelerometer
        if motionManager.isAccelerometerAvailable {
            motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = updateInterval
            motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (accelerometerData: CMAccelerometerData?, NSError) -> Void in

                if let acceleration = accelerometerData?.acceleration {
                    let x = self.roundDouble(value: acceleration.x)
                    let y = self.roundDouble(value: acceleration.y)
                    let z = self.roundDouble(value: acceleration.z)
                    self.notifyAccelerometerObservers(x: x, y: y, z: z)
                }
                if(NSError != nil) {
                    print("\(String(describing: NSError))")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("No Accelerometer Available")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not very helpful. Please update your question and include a description of what was wrong and explain how your answer solves the issue.

Comment: To be honest, this looks a bit over my head, but coincidently, // self.collectionView.reloadData() on the shake event actually reruns the code within my cellForItem(at: function that includes changing the name, which solves the problem. Thanks!